# why is this private method in a constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a bit puzzled by this coding pattern I've run into even though I've been studying up on 'this.' The following (simplified) code shows the pattern:

```
var MyConstructor = function MyConstructor() {
    this._handlers = {
        action: this.handleAction.bind(this)
    };
};

MyConstructor.prototype.start = function(someObj) {
    this.someObj.on(’some event’, this._handlers.action);  //<--here
}

MyConstructor.prototype.handleAction = function() {
    //do stuff
}

module.exports = MyConstructor;
```

My question is, why is the private method in the constructor required? Is this pattern avoid some common problem? Could the line commented `//<--here` simply be:

```
this.someObj.on(’some event’, this.handleAction);
```

Comment: `this.someObj.on(’some event’, this._handlers.action);` sounds to me a lot like an error, maybe you wanted `this[someObj]`?

Comment: @LightStyle i think (hope) the problem doesn't exist in the actual code. It's probably a typo when constructing the example for the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are different. The difference is in *context*, which means the value of `this` within the function.

`this.handleAction` passes the function to `on` without any context. There is no value of `this` specified. The value will be determined when the function is executed. It is very likely that the value will *not* be the a `MyConstructor` object, so `this.start`, for instance, will not refer to the right object, or indeed perhaps any object at all.

The solution is to `bind` context. This sets the context forever, so `this` will always refer to the right value. You see this line of code:

```
action: this.handleAction.bind(this)
```

This means that, when the code later refers to `this._handlers.action`, it will be sending  the function to `on` with the appropriate context, so `this` will always point to the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the following lines

```
this.someObj.on(’some event’, this.handleAction.bind(this));
this.someObj.on(’some event’, this.handleAction);
```

... is that the first handleAction will run with this being the instance of MyConstructor, while the second will run in whatever context the event handling mechanism decides. If it is something like this, it will run with this being the global object:

```
function on (a, callback) {
  callback(); // callback is run with this as the global object 
              // UNLESS it was bound to something else
}
```

The 'private' _handlers property is just an object that holds references to callbacks bound to the instance. If you were to call bind twice, two functions would be created. The _handlers property makes it so that a single bound function is created which can be used as a handler for any number of events.

Comment: A single bound function for every instance of the constructor?!